# Are there any gotchas when using HiLo if you need to use replication later?

Tags: database, replication, hilo

Currently we only use one database server, and that should be all we need for quite some time.  However if I was to convert the database to use HiLo for a POID strategy is there anything I can do now that would make sure I don't have problems with replication later?

Is HiLo even compatible with replication?  I am actually having quite a hard time finding information in regards to this strategy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I, too, found docs on this to be very lacking. Some background on HiLo can be found in [What's the Hi/Lo algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282099/).

In general, it'll be no problem to use replication with this approach. It'll be seen as the db server as no different than any other insert. I guess you'd have to be very careful your clients don't go crazy and step on each others "hi" part of the key.