# Nhibernate with oracle - best way for primary key increment

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

I am using Nhibernate for oracle, and I need to increment my primary key value for each insert. Which one is the best way and efficient way? Oracle sequence, Nhinerbate increment or another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With oracle, you could use `seqhilo`, which uses a database sequence instead of a separate table. You get the advantage of hilo (key generation in memory, no db roundtrip needed) and sequences (no separate transaction needed) at the same time.

Comment: What about nhibernate increment as below? What are disadvantages or advantages?
<id name="Id" column="ID" type="Decimal">
   <generator class="increment" />
</id>

Comment: `increment` does just increment the id in a static variable. This is fast, but does not work when more then one process (or AppDomain) accesses the database. I wouldn't use it except in a very trivial environment (eg. non client server desktop app).

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I am using seqhilo now , but it increments id's not one by one. is it normal?

<id name="Id" column="ID" type="decimal">    
      <generator class="seqhilo">
        <param name="sequence">SEQUENCE_BUNDLE</param>       
      </generator>
    </id>

Comment: This is normal. This is the nature of hilo. It gets a value from the sequence and has a range of numbers free to increment in memory, this way it avoids calling the database for each id.

Comment: do you know a link about seqhilo properties for example "max_lo"?
I'd like to know about the meanings of these properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282099/whats-the-hi-lo-algorithm) in Nhibernate for generating your Ids (for NHibernate it is most preferable way for managing Ids now).