# How do I generate a unique id using Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Lucene to store (as well as index) various documents.

Each document needs a persistent unique identifier (to be used as part of a URL).

If I was using a SQL database, I could use an `integer primary key auto_increment` (or similar) field to automatically generate a unique id for every record that was added.

Is there any way of doing this with Lucene?

I am aware that documents in Lucene are numbered, but have noted that these numbers are reallocated over time.

(I'm using the Java version of Lucene 3.0.3.)

Comment: Cant you just index an UUID.randomUUID() and use it for permanent keys?

Comment: Ideally I want my ids to be shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As larsmans said, you need to store this in a separate field. I suggest that you make the field indexed as well as stored, and index it using a KeywordAnalyzer.
You can keep a counter in memory and update it for each new document.

What remains is the problem of persistence - how to store the maximal id when the Lucene process stops. One possibility is to use a text file which saves the maximal id.

I believe [Flexible Indexing](http://www.box.net/shared/mqhoyz5jv7) will allow you to add the maximal id to the index as a "global" field. If you are willing to work with Lucene's trunk, you can try flexible indexing to see whether it fits the bill.

Answer (score 2):

For similar situations, I use following algorithm (has nothing to do with Lucene, but you can use it anyway).

- Create new `AtomicLong`. Start with initial value obtained from `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `System.nanoTime()`
- Each next ID is generated by calling `.incrementAndGet` or `.getAndIncrement` on that `AtomicLong`.
- if the system is restarted, `AtomicLong` is again initialized to current timestamp during the startup.

**Pros:** simple, effective, thread-safe, non-blocking. If you need clustered id support, just add space for [hi/lo algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282099/whats-the-hi-lo-algorithm) on top of existing long or sacrifice some high bytes.

**Cons:** does not work if the frequency of adding new entities if more than 1/ms (for `System.currentTimeMillis()`) or 1/ns (for `System.nanoTime()`). Does not tolerate clock abnormalities.

Can consider using [UUID](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) as yet another alternative. Probability of a duplicate in UUID is [virtually non-existant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Several commenters have raised possible issues with this approach and I don't have time to test it thoroughly. I'm leaving it here because Yuval F. refers to it. Please don't downvote unnecessarily.

Given an `IndexWriter w`, you can use [`w.maxDoc() + 1`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#maxDoc%28%29) as an id and store that (as a string) in a separate `Field`. Make sure the `Field` is [stored](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.Store.html).

Comment: Why store the id field without indexing it? Doesn't that mean I cannot search by id?

Comment: Also, wouldn't this be affected by merging, and reuse ids when deleted documents are pruned?

Comment: Excuse me @Dave, misread your question. Of course you can index it if you want. @Simon Svensson: the API docs state "Returns total number of docs in this index (...) not counting deletions".

Comment: I don't think this will work. Suppose there are n docs. Add n+1. Delete one. Add another. Now you have two docs with ID n+1. (You'd also get really boned if you merged indexes etc.)

Comment: @Xodarap: If I read the API doc correctly ("not counting deletions") then this approach does guard against that. In fact, that seems to be why `IndexWriter` has both `maxDoc` and `numDocs` methods.

Comment: @larsmans: As Pascal mentions, once you optimize, the seg info no longer contains the count of deleted docs. You can try it with luke: delete, optimize, and then see that the count doesn't include your deletes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find a unique value in the data source you are indexing, and store it in the lucene document. A data source could be a mysql database, files from a file system, etc.

For example, if you are indexing content from a mysql database, you can assemble a unique id using the tablename and primary key id "**tablename_rowID**".

Lets say you are indexing from two tables 'pages' and 'comments' table; for every row in the pages table, you can generate a unique id using "page_28" for row with id 28 in your pages table. Similarly, lets say you index row 36 in comments table, your unique id would be "comment_36".

If all options fail, then I would stick to a UUID. With some additional paranoia, this could be a UUID appended to a timestamp of now().