# Generate unique, random numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am trying to generate unique "referral codes" for unique entries into a "customer" table upon INSERT. I want to do this with a default value constraint.

My question is, how do I **guarantee** that randomly generated values will be unique? I know I can do something like:

```
 SELECT ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)) AS [ReferralCode]
```

Will give me a random integer, but I suspect that it's non-unique.

Help?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need random ids? Or pseudo-random are enough?

Comment: Pseudo-random probably works?

Answer (score 3):

That is what [uniqueidentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) is used for. But that wont work if `int` is a requirement. `Int32` is to small to hold a fairly global unique value.

UPDATE:
If the value only needs to be unique in that table,  just create another column, enable identity and set the seed to some value.

Comment: I'm thinking what I could do is make the ReferralCode column a uniqueidentifier data-type. Then, write a really simple function outside of it to CAST it to an integer. Will that always yield unique integers or am I mistaken?

Comment: @RayBao another option would be to save the Random referral nr. in a column and when a new is generated, check to make sure that it has not already been generated, in that case generate a new. `SELECT CAST(RAND() * 1000000 AS INT)`

Comment: After speaking with a couple other folks, it doesn't seem like we're set on Integer's-only. So that being said, can I get away with a "uniqueidentifier" column and setting the default value to newid() ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you base it off the primary key (assuming int) of the record, plus some big number to make it look random? E.g., (CustomerID+31281923928). This is if you don't mind the values being sequential.

Comment: I guess it depends on what the op means by "unique". If it only needs to be a unique value in that very table, one can just use the pk column. But that wont of course be a globally unique value.

Comment: Yes, it only needs to be unique in this table. I want to avoid using the primary key column.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at some of the [strategies](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/20/nhibernate-poid-generators-revealed.aspx) that are available in something like nhibernate

[What's the Hi/Lo algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282099/whats-the-hi-lo-algorithm)