# Generating short URLs in a distributed data store

Tags: mongodb, distributed, amazon-dynamodb, short-url

Currently I run a web app that heavily relies on short URLs that link to the original content, these URLs need to be as short as possible.

At the moment, I use a simple MySQL data store for storing these objects and an incrementing counter -> base 62 conversion to generate short urls that will grow over time. We need to move to a more distributed and scalable environment.

What is the best way of generating small, unique short Urls for content in a distributed data store? To be specific we plan to use either [Mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you have a look at Jon Skeet's description of the HiLo algorithm here: [What's the Hi/Lo algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282099/whats-the-hi-lo-algorithm)

For the specific use case of mongo, see http://dllhell.net/2010/07/23/on-sequences-with-mongodb-and-norm/

Comment: I started working on a network service that would run on each node in the distributed app (the app servers) and the code would request an ID from the service, the service would allocate a range, say, 4501-5000 and use those, then go get some more, from some atomic counter store... though I wasn't sure if this was the best approach.

Comment: Oh cool! For reference - https://github.com/tarnfeld/snowey :-) Currently I have a redis implementation (for the atomic range store) but i'm working on the dynamodb one.

Comment: Perhaps a larger scale than you'll need, but an interesting project is Twitter's Snowflake: https://github.com/twitter/snowflake#readme

Comment: I spent a lot of time looking into Snowflake and Boundary/flake but the problem with both of those is that they aren't incremental, increasing from small numbers, and turning a snowflake ID into a base 62 string makes it about 18 characters long... which for me is too long.