# URL shortening for NoSQL databases?

Tags: mongodb, url-shortener, nosql

Writing a URL shortener seems fairly straightforward for a traditional database, with a couple notable exceptions:

```
def save_new_url(request):
    url = StoredUrl(url=request.POST['url'])
    url.save()

    url.short_link = base62(url.id)
    url.save()

    return direct_to_template('mytemplate.html', { 'link': url.short_link })
```

The only problem with the above example is the lack of support for known exceptions, URLs which should be reserved for system/site usage, like `account` or `admin`.

How then, can I make a URL shortening service for a NoSQL database like MongoDB, which uses hexadecimal values as keys for its 'rows'? It seems that most URL shorteners work on shortening numbers into `[a-zA-Z0-9]` sets of characters. Since I don't have a number to work with, how can I shorten a URL stored in a MongoDB table?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What issue are you having? There are results like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951163/generating-short-urls-in-a-distributed-data-store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there are many ways you can use the `_id` field in MongoDB. See my answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865382/change-size-of-objectid/15870276#15870276) for some ideas.

Then, if I understand correctly, your question has to do with the fact that SQL DBs have auto-increment counters which are convenient primary keys while NoSQL DBs, like MongoDB, don't, which opens the question about what should you use as the basis for generating a new short URL.

If you want to generate [auto-incrementing IDs in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) there are two main approaches: optimistic loop & maintaining a separate counter collection/doc. Having tried both at scale exceeding 1,000 requests/second, I would recommend the approach based on `findAndModify`.

A good URL shortener design would also include randomization, which in this case would mean leaving random gaps between different auto-incrementing IDs. You can use this by generating a random number on the client and incrementing by that number.

Comment: "Having tried both at scale exceeding 1,000 requests/second, I would recommend the approach based on `findandModify`." - Thank you, that just about sums it up. Was wanting to know how it'd scale.