# how to generate the key in the database when lots of data coming in at the same time?

Tags: database, hibernate, web, architecture, struts2

Using Hibernate, Struts2, Spring framework, which way is better to generate the primary key for database when millions of users submits their informations or orders in the same time ?

there are some options:

1: generate with "uuid"

2: generate with "sequence"

3: your solutions...

(considering the data portability and efficiency )

Comment: And what are the options?

Comment: What is your opinion?

Comment: Have you determined there's actually a reasonable difference in performance?

Comment: I recommond "uuid"，considering the portability and efficiency.
Oracle has the SEQUENCE ,but MySQL not.
but query the ID from the table that is defined varchar2,32 bits uuid will cause some other problems,such as trailing space or any specail characters at the end .
Is there some better ways you genius want to share or teach me ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the database to manage the unique keys, e.g.

```
  INSERT INTO yourTable (yourSequence.nextval(), COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ... )
```

Generating your own key in the application will certainly work, but if the application gets scaled to multiple servers it can cause issues if you don't prepare for that.

If you are using MySQL, you can use AUTO_INCREMENT - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-sequences.htm

Comment: thanks for answering.but it has poor portability for database,you konw MySQL does't have the sequence.

Comment: True, but you can use AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL to replicate the functionality

Answer (score 0):

Look at hibernate generator implementations - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id There are various types.

I prefer HiLo algorithm, see explanation here [What's the Hi/Lo algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282099/whats-the-hi-lo-algorithm) as it provides great throughput for massive data.

[Be aware of Guid](http://martin.podval.eu/2011/06/mssql-primary-key-guid-antipattern.html) as it's not quite good primary key because along with clustered primary index.