# How to auto generate IDs in NHibernate

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How can I make NHibernate autogenerate unique IDs for a table?
The IDs can be any `long` values, as long as each one is only used once.

My current mapping looks like this:

```
<id name="Id">
    <generator class="increment"/>
</id>
```

This creates increasing IDs starting at 1, but it resets to 1 at each application startup. So the after each restart, the first element that is stored gets the Id 1 and the previous Id 1 element is deleted (not what I want).

Edit: The reason for this is that I used `SchemaExport` instead of `SchemaUpdate`, so my entire database was deleted at each application startup.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is clear documentation section about it. I would suggest to use HI-LO (see [What's the Hi/Lo algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/282099/1679310))

#### [5.1.5.1. generator](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator)

**increment**

generates identifiers of any integral type that are unique only when no other process is inserting data into the same table. Do not use in a cluster.

**identity**

supports identity columns in DB2, MySQL, MS SQL Server and Sybase. The identifier returned by the database is converted to the property type using Convert.ChangeType. Any integral property type is thus supported.

**sequence**

uses a sequence in DB2, PostgreSQL, Oracle or a generator in Firebird. The identifier returned by the database is converted to the property type using Convert.ChangeType. Any integral property type is thus supported.

**hilo**

uses a hi/lo algorithm to efficiently generate identifiers of any integral type, given a table and column (by default hibernate_unique_key and next_hi respectively) as a source of hi values. The hi/lo algorithm generates identifiers that are unique only for a particular database. Do not use this generator with a user-supplied connection.

You can use the "where" parameter to specify the row to use in a table. This is useful if you want to use a single tabel for your identifiers, with different rows for each table.

**seqhilo**

uses a hi/lo algorithm to efficiently generate identifiers of any integral type, given a named database sequence.

**uuid.hex**

uses System.Guid and its ToString(string format) method to generate identifiers of type string. The length of the string returned depends on the configured format.

**uuid.string**

uses a new System.Guid to create a byte[] that is converted to a string. 
guid

uses a new System.Guid as the identifier.

**guid.comb**

uses the algorithm to generate a new System.Guid described by Jimmy Nilsson in the article http://www.informit.com/articles/article.asp?p=25862.

**native**

picks identity, sequence or hilo depending upon the capabilities of the underlying database.

**assigned**

lets the application to assign an identifier to the object before Save() is called.

**foreign**

uses the identifier of another associated object. Usually used in conjunction with a `<one-to-one>` primary key association.

Comment: Is the increment generator not supposed to generate unique IDs? I don't like the hilo generator because it needs two additional columns as I understand it.

Comment: Honestly, my experience is, that increment is working properly. It does not start from 1 on app restart. It gets the last max value and continues incrementing it. So, maybe you do not experience that kind of problem, but something else. BUT. Increment is good only in single thread world (very unique cases) HI-LO is safe all the time, but you must be ready to accept not linear IDs... some numbers will be skipped. Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: I was using `SchemaExport`instead of `SchemaUpdate`, that's why I lost my database on application startup. I'm now using Hilo as you suggested and it works fine!

Comment: Great to see that, really. Enjoy NHibernate ;)