# Is RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(30) a valid GUID strategy?

Tags: java, guid, uuid, distributed-computing, primary-key-design

I need a random string generator that generates an ***alpha-numeric*** string to use as an ***unique*** key in a distributed system that is ***30 characters or less***. It cannot contain any special characters.

Will [RandomStringUtils#randomAlphanumeric](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#randomAlphanumeric(int)) work for this?

The underlying implementation uses `java.util.Random`.

The set of unique keys will probably be less than 100 billion, and the system needs to be able to handle up to 1000 records per second.

How can I prove that this strategy has a low enough probability of collision to work as a primary key generator?

Comment: How about generating identifiers using low and high ids? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282099/whats-the-hi-lo-algorithm)

Answer (score 4):

java.util.Random implements a LCG algorithm and its period is 2^48 numbers, so RandomStringUtils will be as good as this implementation and 100 billion of 30-character strings would require ~ 1% of 2^48 random elements.

Note that java.util.Random is not cryptographically secure, so given some GUIDs it is possible to infer the next one, so I'd use another implementation that uses a cryptographically secure random number generator (e.g. java.util.SecureRandom).

Comment: Thanks for answering! Can you explain your quantitative figures;  `its period`?? and `~ 1% of 2^48`

Comment: Using java.util.Random, after 2^48 invocations you'll start getting the same numbers. In your case you need 100 billion of 30-character strings, so it means 3 trillion of random elements, and 3 trillion is approx. 1% of 2^48, meaning that you can generate 100 times 100 billion of 30-character strings before the sequence is repeated.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. Are you sure the algorithm does not repeat a sequence of chars until all combinations are exhausted?

Comment: This is the theory for LCG, although java.util.Random doesn't state this fact explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't want to use `java.util.UUID` class? It returns random UUID of 32bit characters String.
Example implementation:

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class GenerateUUID {

   public static final void main(String... aArgs){
     //generate random UUIDs
     UUID idOne = UUID.randomUUID();
     UUID idTwo = UUID.randomUUID();
     log("UUID One: " + idOne);
     log("UUID Two: " + idTwo);
   }

   private static void log(Object aObject){
     System.out.println(String.valueOf(aObject));
   }
}
```

Comment: `UUID()` has more than 30 chars, and `Base64(UUID().bytes)` contains non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

Random is not unique. Using random number generation to get "unique" values runs into the Birthday Problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack. This turns the a 1 in 2^48 probability into a 1 in 2^24 probability, which you'll end up hitting quicker than you think. Use UUIDs; they're designed to be universally unique.

32 characters:

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString.replace("-","")
```

22 characters:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
String uuidStr = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16])
    .putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits())
    .putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits())
            .array()).replace("=", "");
```