# How to pass DateTime.Ticks as URI parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

How can I get this code working?

```
public ActionResult ABC(DateTime.Now.Ticks Id)
{
 //some stuff
 return View();
}
```

Your thoughts?

**EDIT**
The whole concept is have unique URLs for each and every visitor/user.

Comment: You should use type instead of `DateTime.Now.Ticks`. So, how about `long Id`?

Comment: Is that unique for every visitor? @SonerGönül

Comment: How r u calling action, what issue, add that part also

Comment: @Dawar: If it's received as a URI parameter, callers can put whatever they like on it. I could hit http://yourserver/ABC?Id=10 a hundred times, and so could someone else. You can't rely on external sources not under your control for uniqueness.

Comment: @JonSkeet how to avoid that situation? I need a hint to start learning about it.

Comment: My answer gives several suggestions. Fundamentally you need to understand that parameters for methods like this are provided by the clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the basics: when declaring a method, you need to specify the *type* of the parameter, which in this case would be `long`:

```
public ActionResult Abc(long id)
{
    // ...
}
```

When you *call* that (whether internally or whether it's responding to a URL, e.g. generated in Javascript), you can choose to use `DateTime.Now.Ticks` as the *argument* to do, just as you could call the method like this inside the application:

```
Foo.Abc(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

However some warnings:

- There's no guarantee that callers *will* use that as the argument
- Even if they did, it will be the current time in their *system local* time zone, which is almost certainly a bad idea
- If you're trying to use a number of ticks as an ID, that's also a bad idea:

  - `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` will return the same value multiple times when called in quick succession
  - Multiple machines could call the method at the same time anyway

If your idea is to generate a unique ID, I'd probably just go with `Guid.NewGuid()`... or whatever your storage layer provides for generating unique IDs. Even keeping an internal, atomically-incremented counter on the machine has problems in terms of scaling horizontally. That's sometimes solved using a [high-low ID generation strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282099/whats-the-hi-lo-algorithm).

Comment: any alternative to skip those warnings?

Comment: @Dawar: Which warnings? The ones in my answer? You're being very unclear - but please read my complete answer carefully. I think you need to re-examine your whole understanding of how URI parameters should be treated.

Comment: @Dawar: If your fundamental goal is to get something into production quickly without caring at all about uniqueness, then you can certainly ignore all the warnings in my post. However, I would **very strongly** urge you not to do so. What's the point of asking a client to supply an ID if you can't reasonably expect it to be unique?

Comment: The whole concept is to have unique URLs for different users/visitors.

Comment: @Dawar: But the visitor decides the URL - so how are you expecting to *force* them to be unique? If one of your visitors emails a URL to another person, you can obviously have two different users hitting that URL at the same time. Take a step back and think about what you're really trying to achieve - but Stack Overflow is *not* for ongoing discussion.