# Could we use AddAsync() with any entity that has a primary key property in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

As far as I know, it's not recommended to use `AddAsync()` in every situation. based on [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-6.0).

> This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used.

And a [PrimaryKey is considered as a generated value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#primary-keys), so it means that it's possible to use an async method.

Does it mean that whenever we have a `[key]` in an entity we can use `AddAsync()` to add it to the database?

Comment: Well all entities  compatible with the change-tracker must have a key defined in the net core db model so you can call .AddAsync on those entities (so not keyless entities ofc). so yes you definitely can - are you asking whether there are any negative impacts or why would you like to know this?

Comment: @sommmen Yes, it would be good to know about the negative impacts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AddAsync() vs Add() in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135262/addasync-vs-add-in-ef-core)

Comment: In that case i'm voting to close as a dupe - since  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52318741/4122889 answers this question. Basically: Yes use AddAsync in an Async context and use Add in a sync context - don't bother with the async overhead - optimize your queries will yield better results.

Comment: @sommmen Honestly not completely, and I've seen that question before, I just wanted to make sure that is it possible to use async with all entities which have `[key]` or not.

Comment: Okay well - yes, just try it - it works great. I use a combination in my app and it works as it should.