# The "FirstOrDefaultAsync" method -- Does it trigger EF to start tracking the given entity

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, linq, entity-framework-core

Does the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` method provided by `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` trigger Entity Framework (EF) to start tracking a given entity?

For example, as far as I understand, the `AddAsync` method "tells" EF to start tracking a given entity.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. All functions which returns single or collection of FULL items (not custom projected via `Select`) are tracked by EF Core automatically.

Comment: @topsail 

I started a new job and am trying to understand an existing codebase. I'll provide what I can below.

Comment: "Yes. All functions which returns single or collection of FULL items (not custom projected via Select) are tracked by EF Core automatically. – 
Svyatoslav Danyliv"

Thanks for your input.

@wenbingeng-MSFT seems to think differently (see their answer below).

Answer (score 0):

The `FirstOrDefaultAsync` method is used to retrieve the first element that satisfies the specified criteria, or the default value if no such element is found. It is a query method that does not involve modifying the state of the entity or instructing EF to track the entity.

`AddAsync()` is 100% async safe, while `Add()` is only async safe in certain conditions.
For details, you can refer to [AddAsync() vs Add() in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135262/addasync-vs-add-in-ef-core)

None of these are directly related to tracking a given entity.

For tracking a given entity, you can pay more attention to `SaveChanges`, the following is an example, by catching `DbUpdateException` to track entities and fields, because `DbUpdateException` is usually an error reported in `SaveChanges`:

```
         try
         {

             using (var context = new EfContext())
             {

                 var data = new TestTable
                 {
                     Status = TestTableStatus.Status1.ToString(),
                     Content = "One-to-many test",
                     TestTableItems = new List<TestTableItem> {
                     new TestTableItem { Name = "Add one-to-many 1", Id = 123},

                     new TestTableItem {Name = "Add one-to-many 2" } }
                 };

                 context. Add(data);

                 await context. SaveChangesAsync();
             }
         }
         catch (DbUpdateException ex)
         {

             var failedEntries = ex.Entries;
             foreach (var entry in failedEntries)
             {
                 var entityName = entry. Metadata. Name;
                 Console.WriteLine($"Failed to add in entity: {entityName}");

             }
         }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input! One of the other folks who replied seems to disagree with you (I say that respectfully). 

@Svyatoslav Danyliv said, "Yes. All functions which returns single or collection of FULL items (not custom projected via Select) are tracked by EF Core automatically."

I need a tie breaker answer I suppose. Funny enough, Chat GPT was giving me mixed signals as well which is why I came here! :o)

Comment: @Kyle Hi, it seems you have misunderstood me a bit. I agree with Svyatoslav Danyliv. But it doesn't seem to be the code you pointed out that actually does the tracking for a given entity. Instead, SaveChanges. I hope my answer can help you

Comment: @wenbengeng-MSFT

Thank you for your time! 

Here's some example code that is illustrative of my actual code. Assume `context` is an instance of a `DbContext`, `Characteristic` is a property of `context` and also an instance of `DbSet`, and `id` is a parameter passed by the calling method. Furthermore, assume `Characteristic` has an int `Id` property and a boolean `IsActive` property.

`var entity = context.Characteristic.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id.Equals(id));
entity.IsActive = false;
context.SaveChangesAsync();`

Which of those prior lines of code "tells" EF to start tracking?

Comment: @Kyle Hi, start tracking from "var entity = context.Characteristic.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id.Equals(id));", here it is context that plays a role in tracking. But it is easier to catch the tracked entity by DbUpdateException at "context.SaveChangesAsync();", as shown in the above code.

Comment: Thank you! So just to clarify, you're saying the line `context.Characteristic.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id.Equals(id))` is where EF starts to track the entity?

Comment: @Kyle Yes, if my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people