# Get the next Object Id before create the object for a Model Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, information-schema

I have a `Model` I need to get the next record id which is going to be create before create that object in my model like:

```
MyModel.last.id #=> 10
MyModel.last.destroy
MyModel.last.id #=> 9, so (Model.last.id + 1) would be 10... but...
MyModel.create  #=> 11, my next id was actually 11
```

Can you please suggest a better way to solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: I think you need a [HiLo id generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282099/whats-the-hi-lo-algorithm) here. Bad news is, it's not very common in rails. In fact, I haven't seen a single usage of it in my practice. But the idea is solid.

Comment: I cannot think of any good use case for this. As @SergioTulentsev points out, most ways of actually **using** this information will entail race conditions.

Comment: @MoMolog: there are atomic/safe ways of getting the next id (sequences in PG, for example). As for how it can be used: preparing a graph of interconnected objects and inserting them all at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the table's AUTO_INCREMENT value. MySQL stores such metadata in the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html) database. The AUTO_INCREMENT values can be found in the [TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html) table. The table contains one entry for each database and table.

I don't think Rails or the MySQL gem provide any built-in method for fetching it.

I have used something like this in one of my previous projects:

```
# config/initializers/auto_increment.rb

module AutoIncrement
  def auto_increment_value
    connection.execute(<<-SQL.squish).first[0]
      SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
        FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES`
       WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = '#{connection.current_database}'
         AND `TABLE_NAME` = '#{table_name}'
    SQL
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.extend(AutoIncrement)
```

You can then execute:

```
MyModel.auto_increment_value
```

and it will return the current value for the table's AUTO_INCREMENT value, e.g. `11`.

Note that it is not safe to use that value as an explicit ID for your record. You should let MySQL handle the assignment of new IDs – that's what AUTO_INCREMENT is for.

Comment: Isn't this _extremely_ prone to race conditions?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it just fetches a value from a database table. What do you mean?

Comment: two threads fetch the same value and try to use it as id. Or simply doing this select also magically updates the counter?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev two threads fetching and using the same value creates a race condition, not the above code. I don't know why the OP needs the ID beforehand or how it is going to be used.

Comment: Fair enough. Anyway, I thought a warning would not hurt :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev your right, I've added a warning. I used that code to check if the highest id matches the AUTO_INCREMENT value to determine whether the latest record was deleted – the user was given the option to re-use that id then.

Answer (score 1):

Why worry about the id? If you have some other reasons for a contiguous number, use another field and do some select max on a before_create.

FWIW, MySQL, and Mariadb auto increment only resets on a database restart, which avoids race situations.