# Why Entity Framework have AddAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I understand why EF have `ToListAsync` or `SaveChangesAsync` - because it waits for db operation execution. But `AddAsync` just returns `Task.FromResult` - so why is there the `AddAsync` method? And why should I use it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-2.1):

> This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used.

[SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.sqlservervaluegenerationstrategy?view=efcore-2.1):

> A sequence-based hi-lo pattern where blocks of IDs are allocated from the server and used client-side for generating keys.

See also [What's the Hi/Lo algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282099/whats-the-hi-lo-algorithm)