# What is the difference between AddRange and AddRangeAsync in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core to insert entries and I noticed that when I debug this line of code `context.MyEntityDbSet.AddRangeAsync(records)` it takes a second to load as opposed to `context.MyEntityDbset.AddRange(records)` it happens instantly. Is there a DB call happening when calling the `AddRangeAsync` method? Is it any different than the `AddRange` one?

Comment: I think this link is helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addrangeasync?view=efcore-2.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the official [EF Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.addrangeasync?view=efcore-2.1), the method `AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity>, CancellationToken)` is used when working with special value generators that require a database round trip. For instance, if your application employs `SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo` to allocate blocks of IDs in advance, when a new entity is tracked by EF it might need first to query the database and ask for a new "Hi" (you can learn more about the Hi/Lo algorithm here: [What's the Hi/Lo algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282099/whats-the-hi-lo-algorithm)). Therefore, `AddRangeAsync` is applicable in scenarios where EF Core requires to communicate with the database to obtain ID blocks in advance. On the other hand, when the objective is simply to mark an entity as added — without the necessity for `SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo` or similar mechanisms — the `AddRange` method is more appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

Most likely yes. From the docs :

> This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used.

This means you *shouldn't* use AddRangeAsync unless you use one of those value generators that need access to the database before they generate a value.

Using IDENTITY or a sequence to provide the key value doesn't require an explicit database access. The key values are generated when the rows are inserted in the tables

**About HiLo**

This is a safe strategy for generating keys on the client side. The server generates a `High` value for each *client*, which is why a database access is required. The client then starts incrementing a "low" value and adding it to the server's high value to generate unique keys. This ensures that two clients will never create the same value.

It also allows the client to know the key value before the data is actually inserted in the database

**Unsafe strategies - MAX +1**

An *unsafe* strategy that almost guarantees duplicates is to calculate the maximum value of a key and start incrementig from that. Apart from the obvious cost of calculating MAX, multiple clients can *easily* read the same MAX value and start creating duplicate values.

Even worse, deleting the latest rows will create new keys with the same values as the already deleted rows. Any other tables that used the old IDs as references will end up pointing to the wrong rows.

Answer (score -3):

[Asynchronous queries avoid blocking a thread while the query is executed in the database.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async)

Comment: The answer would be more helpful if it included an explanation instead of just a link.