# When would you use GUIDs as primary keys?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, guid, uuid, microsoft-sync-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advantages and disadvantages of GUID / UUID database keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-guid-uuid-database-keys)

Are there any circumstances where it is essential to use GUIDs as primary keys in a SQL Server 2005/8 DB. For example, does the use of the MS Sync Framework force this, or data replication?

Comment: Sorry, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-guid-uuid-database-keys.
I'll close it now!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would use guids as a key if you needed multiple databases synchronising via replication.

Another reason to use guids is if you wanted to create rows on some remote client eg a winforms app and then submit those to the server via web services etc.

If you do this I would strongly suggest that you make sure that you specify your own clustered index based on an auto incrementing int that is not unique.  It can be a considerable overhead inserting rows into a table where the clustered index is a guid.

Update: Here is an example of how to set up a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable](
[intId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[realGuidId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[someData] [varchar](50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_myTable] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
   [realGuidId] ASC
    )
)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_myTable] ON [dbo].[myTable] 
(
[intId] ASC
)
```

You would insert into the table as normal e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(NEWID(), 'Some useful data goes here')
```

Update: I listened to a really good dotnetrocks episode that talks about this its worth a listen - [Show #447](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=447)

Comment: Just to be clear, I'd leave my PK as a GUID for distribution/replication purposes (something we need), but introduce a new non-unique clustered index that may (after replication) contain multiple identical entries. How do I then get SQL Server to use this index when inserting rather than the PK, or is it automatic?

Comment: +1 for the separate clustered index. NEVER use a guid as a clustered index, the performance is abismal.

Comment: Just a comment, you could use the new newsequentialid() functionality (assuming Sql Server) that would give you sequentially increasing guids which can be used for clustered indexes. Randomly distributed data (clustered index on newid()) may improve performance if you use partitions where the random locations gives that the data is written to different harddrives.

Comment: Or find some natural data to use as the clustered index: for example the 'company name' or 'location' or something like that.

Comment: What good is a separate clustered index if its an unused column?

Comment: Performance mostly.  It keeps the size of the all indexes down and it will help prevent index fragmentation you get when using guids as keys.

Comment: UPDATE: Turns out that using non-sequential GUIDs as clustered indexes can actually be GREAT for performance, because in high I/O systems, the page splits are FAR cheaper than the contention caused by trying to insert everything on the last page when using sequential IDs: http://blog.kejser.org/2011/10/05/boosting-insert-speed-by-generating-scalable-keys/

Answer (score 3):

I am using GUIDs as primary keys, because I don't want to have composite primary keys when I am building applications with distributed databases and one central database that is synchronized with data from all the distributed ones. With GUIDs I am sure (almost*) I will not have a conflict (constraint violation) when I pull data from all the DBs into the central one.

* it is highly unlikely having the same GUID generated in two different places, but not impossible.

Comment: The risk of a GUID clash is one I am willing to take ;)

Comment: Yes don't get me wrong. Although the probability of this happening is not 0, GUIDs are very suitable for that kind of use. :-)

Comment: Just make sure you're not using your GUID's as the CLUSTERED index in SQL Server - they are horrible in that way. Use an INT (IDENTITY) or something like that - much better.

Answer (score 2):

When the database isn't centralized or some of the collection is performed remotely.