# Getting the index number in database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table with Guid column as primary key.

[image]

How can I get the row index of a column using entity framework. For example I want to get the row index of Grapes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Row Index in a list by using entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259737/get-row-index-in-a-list-by-using-entity-framework)

Comment: And you have accounted for a GUID being a poor choice for a primary key?

Comment: @Jaycee GUID as primary key is not a poor choice.. see this article http://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/

Comment: I would do a bit more research if I were you, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897083/when-would-you-use-guids-as-primary-keys/897112#897112  Perhaps the GUIDs fit your scenario who knows

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of the element directly if  your list has implemented indexer.

In your case, for example if you want the Grapes index you can do this (I do not recommend using it in tables with many elements because from the point of view of the performance ToList() is bad):

```
Table test= Table.Where<Table>( x => return x.Name== "Grapes";).Single<Table>();
int index = Table.ToList().IndexOf(test);
```