# Django Encrypt the URL (PK and ID)

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I am trying to find best solution for encrypting my URL, I have found some old versions, for python 2.2.
I need to set my URLs, not to display like this:
`.com/AddPost/1`/ and `.com/PostDetail/40`.
But something like this:`.com/AddPost/DMQRzZWMDdGQtbndzBHNsawN0aXRsZQR0ZXN0AzcwMQR3b2UDMjQwMjEwNQ`
That you can not guess what PK is and access that page:

URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('PostDetail/<int:pk>', PostDetail.as_view(), name ='post_detail'), ]
```

view.py:

```
class PostDetail(DetailView): 
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args,**kwargs):
       post = Post.objects.all()
       context = super(PostDetail,self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
       stuff = get_object_or_404(Post,id=self.kwargs['pk'])
       total_likes=stuff.total_likes()
       context['total_likes'] = total_likes
       return context
```

Comment: Instead of encrypting the urls look into using [slugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/what-is-a-slug-in-django) which is a more user friendly and simpler solution.

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37001188/10428131