# Is the primary key useful when is never used

Tags: sql-server

the question is about table2.id

Table1

```
id     -- Uniqueidentifier primary key
```

Table2

```
id        -- Uniqueidentifier primary key
id_table1 -- Duplicate foreign key
value     -- varchar or other
```

The possible queries are :

```
select table1.id, table2.value 
from table1
inner join table2 ON table2.id_table1 = table1.id
where table1.id = 'foo'
```

or

```
select value
from table2
where table2.id_table1 = 'foo'
```

Are the performance changed with or without the existence of table2.id. Even if queries doesn't use it?

Comment: If these are all the queries, why bother adding the id column to the second table? just use the combination of `id_table1` and `value` as a primary key. If you already have a clustered unique index on that combination, it will not effect performance, only storage size.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-guid-uuid-database-keys

Comment: @IvanStarostin While an interesting reading, the link you provided has no barring on the question itself. Whether the OP should use an int or guid is a totally different question then the one posted.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I know. At first I wanted to add _"you are asking wrong question"_ to my comment with that link. I guess he wouldn't ask anything without having troubles. And primary key column itself does not provide any troubles while `guid+clustered` combination _sometimes_ does. Not sure if idea of `guid+something` as clustered pk is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is yes. Having columns and indexes you will never use will have a negative performance impact although maybe not much depending on your exact situation.

I think though that what you really need is a better understanding of primary keys and indexes. In particular I recommend you research the debate on surrogate keys. You will find plenty of info on the topic.