# Cloud functions HTTPS trigger to generate unique user IDs

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, app-inventor

For an AppInventor app which uses Firebase as database, I want to give unique user IDs to app users. After looking for some options I had the idea that I could use a Cloud HTTP function to be requested by the app, and the returning data would be a `UserId` generated by simply incrementing the last `UserId` in the `UserIds` table (not sure if it is one, either).

That's the story, but I can't make the following code to deploy (and when I can, it doesn't work as I expect). It reads the last `UserId` correctly, but I could only make it overwrite the previous data so far.

It throws an unexpected token error in the `"."` in `functions.https`.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Import and initialize the Firebase Admin SDK.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var LastUserId = function f() {return admin.database().ref('UserIds').limitToLast(1)}

exports.addWelcomeMessages = functions.https.onRequest((request, response)) => {
    var ref = admin.database().ref('UserIds');
    // this new, empty ref only exists locally
    var newChildRef = ref.push();
    // we can get its id using key()
    console.log('my new shiny id is '+newChildRef.key());
    // now it is appended at the end of data at the server
    newChildRef.set({User : LastUserId + 1});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Authentication package provides an automatically generated unique ID for every authenticated user already, which you can obtain from [`firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#uid) on web and similar methods for other platforms.

If you still want to generate your own incremental ID using Cloud Functions, you'll need to make use of a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#transaction) and then send back the new ID, something like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.generateUserId = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var ref = admin.database().ref('/lastUserId');
    ref.transaction(function(current) {
      return (current || 0) + 1;
    }, function(error, committed, snapshot) {
      if (error || !committed || !snapshot) {
        console.error("Transaction failed abnormally!", error || "");
      } else {
        console.log("Generated ID: ", snapshot.val());
      }
      res.status(200).send(snapshot.val().toString());
    });
});
```

This increments the `lastUserId` value in the database using a transaction and then sends this new ID back as a response (using [`res.send()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions)) for use in the calling app.

Comment: does this write to the database as well as I'm trying to do here: `newChildRef.set({User : LastUserId + 1});`

Comment: Yes, the transaction will write back to the same location any value that is returned, so `return (current || 0) + 1;` will increment the current value by 1 (starting at 0 if `lastUserId` doesn't exist) and then save it back to the database automatically.

Comment: Database is written ok, but I'm getting error in the logs and it doesnt return the written data: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
    at admin.database.ref.transaction.then (/user_code/index.js:15:38)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)`
any ideas?

Comment: Oops, sorry that's my fault, I didn't actually test the code! See updated code which I've reworked & tested.

Comment: What you could also consider, is using GUID / UUIDs - They have some benefits in terms of creating them prior insertion time. You can read some more about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-guid-uuid-database-keys