# Mysql Group By condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to Apply condition for `GROUP BY`.

When the condition `city_id != 0` is true, group the list. Otherwise normal list.

I used this query for that:

```
(
    SELECT city_id, sum(sales) as counts
    FROM product_sales
    WHERE city_id !=0     
    GROUP BY city_id
)
UNION
(
    SELECT city_id, sales 
    FROM product_sales  
    WHERE city_id =0     
    ORDER BY sales_id 
)
```

Anyone can help me avoid the `UNION` and get the list in a single query?

Comment: What's wrong with UNION?

Answer (score 4):

One idea : `GROUP BY` the `city_id` when it is not zero, else emulate a random unique value for grouping with [`UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid). So each row with `city_id = 0` will not be grouped.

```
select city_id, sum(sales)
from product_sales
group by
  case when city_id = 0
  then UUID()
  else city_id
  end
```

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7b1e/6/0)

> A UUID is designed as a number that is globally unique in space and
>   time. Two calls to UUID() are expected to generate two different
>   values, even if these calls are performed on two separate computers
>   that are not connected to each other.

Comment: `when city_id = 0` should be `when city_id <> 0`

Comment: @hjpotter92 : are you sure? I re-read the question and I'm pretty sure the condition is right.

Comment: SELECT city_id, sum(sales) as counts
    FROM product_sales
    WHERE city_id !=0

Comment: If the city is different from 0, then we group by city_id, it is what the OP ask.

Comment: This answer seems to be my solution but is there some drawbacks using UUID like this???

Comment: you can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-guid-uuid-database-keys) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949/whats-your-opinion-on-using-uuids-as-database-row-identifiers-particularly-in). It doesn't exactly talk about using it for random sorting, but it still has interesting point.