# Why does a database have a weird alphanumeric key

Tags: sql-server, primary-key-design

I am trying to connect data in two databases, both created automatically by a different UI application. In one, all the keys are in this format "D8FC23D7-97D6-42F5-A52F-1CE93087B3A4".

Is there any reason this would be done? I also saw keys that look similar in a GIS database. I can't tell if these are supposed to be some computed key, maybe to detect what I am trying to do, or just random with some other intent.

PS I am using SQL Server. From what I can gather, this is not something that would be auto generated by SQL Server.

Comment: It's called a `GUID`.  And yes, it is something that can be auto-generated `SELECT NEWID()`

Comment: ... and it's a poor choice for a primary key. [well, at least as a clustered index.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938044/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-a-guid-as-a-primary-key-specifically-rega)

Comment: Sometimes it's called a unique identifier.  These can be generated by a variety of programming languages, so don't jump to any conclusions.

Comment: The advantage of using a `GUID` over some other numeric `ID` is that it can hold **5,316,911,983,139,663,491,615,228,241,121,400,000** different, unique values.  Honestly, though, if you need more than a `BIGINT`'s measly **9,223,372,036,854,775,807** distinct, (positive) values, you need to re-evaluate your data model.  To get an idea about the sheer number of `GUID`s there are, [this is an excellent read.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2977648/3393505)

Comment: A better discusion of this can be found [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949/whats-your-opinion-on-using-uuids-as-database-row-identifiers-particularly-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a GUID, also called UUID, a universally unique identifier (confer, for example, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) or [rfc4122](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt)). The idea behind a guid is that applications can generate identifiers, that are globally unique, without the need of a central unit doing any choreography (see motivation from rfc4122 below).

Various systems, databases, and programming languages offer functionality for generating UUIDs (e.g. `SELECT NEWID()` in sql server); the benefit is that with UUID generators, application can generate globally identified units in autarkical manner.

UUIDs can serve as database keys, though in most cases you will find much more lightweight and much more proper keys.

> One of the main reasons for using UUIDs is that no centralized
>   authority is required to administer them (although one format uses
>   IEEE 802 node identifiers, others do not).  As a result, generation
>   on demand can be completely automated, and used for a variety of
>   purposes.  The UUID generation algorithm described here supports very 
>   high allocation rates of up to 10 million per second per machine if
>   necessary, so that they could even be used as transaction IDs.
>
> UUIDs are of a fixed size (128 bits) which is reasonably small
>   compared to other alternatives.  This lends itself well to sorting,
>   ordering, and hashing of all sorts, storing in databases, simple
>   allocation, and ease of programming in general.
>
> Since UUIDs are unique and persistent, they make excellent Uniform 
>   Resource Names.  The unique ability to generate a new UUID without a
>   registration process allows for UUIDs to be one of the URNs with the
>   lowest minting cost.

Comment: One bit of trivia: GUID is Microsoft's implementation of UUID. So, GUIDs are UUIDs but the converse isn't necessarily true.

Comment: does this mean I should just be able to create one entry, or is the algorithm what makes it universal?

Comment: since i can't edit: In reply to my comment, NEWID() mentioned above seems to work well to generate the key, which really answers my question I think.